# Google Map API for android development

Tags: android, google-maps

In my project auto complete list drop down has small amount of data, it is not as same as displayed in Google map and when I search a place nearby in google map there are over hundred of restaurant is shown but in my project I can get only less than fifty place.

Version used : Google map api version 2.

Answer (score 1):

May be you are searching for specific places like restaurant only. Some restaurant may be search with restaurant|bar|something(those are known as in Google search api).